# Loading a big table, referenced by others, efficiently

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

My use case is the following:

I have big table `users` (~200 millions rows) of users with `user_id` as the primary key. `users` is referenced by several other tables using foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Every day I have to replace the whole content of `users` using a lot of csv files. (Please don't ask why I have to do that, I just have to...)

My idea was to set the primary key and all foreign keys as DEFERRED, then, in the same transaction, DELETE the whole table and copying all the csvs using the COPY command. The expected result was that all check and index calculation would happen at the end of the transaction.
But actually the insert process is super slow (4hours, against 10min if I insert and the put the primary key) AND no foreign key can refer to a deferrable primary.
I can't remove the primary key during the insertion because of the foreign keys. I don't want get rid of the foreign key either because I would have to simulate the behavior of `ON DELETE CASCADE` manually.

**So basically I am looking for a way to tell postgres to not care about primary key index or foreign key check until the very end of the transaction.**

PS1: I made up the users table, I am actually working with very different kind of data but it's not really relevant to the problem.

PS2: As a rough estimation I would say that every day, on my 200+ millions records, I have 10 records removed, 1million updated and 1million added.

Comment: Can't you insert into a new table, then `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN (... FROM new_table)`, and finally `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...` all the rest?

Comment: That was actually my first approach but that is way way too slow.

Comment: How many of the records do actually change?

Comment: @joop let me update my question, since your question is very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full delete + a full insert will cause a flood of cascading FK,
which will have to be postponed by DEFERRED, 
which will cause an avalanche of aftermath for the DBMS at commit time.

Instead, dont {delete+create} keys, but keep them right where they are.
Also, dont touch records that dont need to be touched.

```
        -- staging table
CREATE TABLE tmp_users AS SELECT * FROM big_users WHERE 1=0;

COPY TABLE tmp_users (...) FROM '...' WITH CSV;
-- ... and more copying ...
-- ... from more files ...

        -- If this fails, you have a problem!
ALTER TABLE tmp_users
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

-- [EDIT]
-- I added this later, because the user_comments table
-- was not present in the original question.
DELETE FROM user_comments c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tmp_users u WHERE u.id = c.user_id
    );
        -- These deletes are allowed to cascade
        -- [we assume that the mport of the CSV files was complete, here ...]
DELETE FROM big_users b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tmp_users t
        WHERE t.id = b.id
        );

        -- Only update the records that actually **change**
        -- [ updates are expensive in terms of I/O, because they create row-versions
        -- , and the need to delete the old row-versions, afterwards ]
        -- Note that the key (id) does not change, so there will be no cascading.
        -- ------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE big_users b
SET name_1 = t.name_1
        , name_2 = t.name_2
        , address = t.address
        -- , ... ALL THE COLUMNS here, except the key(s)
FROM tmp_users t
WHERE  t.id = b.id
AND (t.name_1, t.name_2, t.address, ...) -- ALL THE COLUMNS, except the key(s)
        IS DISTINCT FROM
        (b.name_1, b.name_2, b.address, ...)
        ;

        -- Maybe there were some new records in the CSV files. Add them.
INSERT INTO big_users (id,name_1,name_2,address, ...)
SELECT id,name_1,name_2,address, ...
FROM tmp_users t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM big_users x
        WHERE x.id = t.id
        );
```

Comment: Insert is taking way too long because of the insert

Comment: Note: it inserts only the 10 million records that need to be inserted. Should be somewhere between 4 hrs and 10 min, unless you do something very wrong. (such as dropping the index)

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution :

```
update pg_index set indisvalid = false, indisready=false where indexrelid= 'users_pkey'::regclass;
DELETE FROM users;
COPY TABLE users FROM 'file.csv';
REINDEX INDEX users_pkey;
DELETE FROM user_comments c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id = c.user_id )
commit;
```

The magic dirty hack is to disable the primary key index in the postgres catalog and at the end to force the reindexing (which will override what we changed). I can't use foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` because for some reason it makes the constraint being executed immediatly... So instead my foreign keys are `ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` and I have to do the delete myself.

This works well in my case because only a few users are being referred in other tables.

I wish there was a cleaner solution though...